# What new Widgets in Rebol 3 Vid?

Tags: rebol

Rebol 2 VID was hugely missing Dropdownlist and Treeview, I have made a search on Rebol 3 on Google but couldn't find anything except a discussion. So what will Rebol 3 VID really include as new widgets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drop-down list is available in r2 already.  I too was looking for that. check car's blog about submitting forms using cgi.

Comment: I'm not talking about cgi of course :) I'm talking about VID there is no dropdownlist in STANDARD.

Comment: ok you're right http://www.rebol.com/docs/quick-start6.html

Answer (score 1):

yes in the cgi example, he uses VID to display his form  and there is drop down list there. Check his blog/example "about submitting forms to server" .

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Rebol3 GUI will include the widgets that the community builds as, to the best of my knowledge, it will be open source.

I really think that there are better forums than Stack Overflow to ask questions like this where you can even get involved in shaping the future of Rebol. Take the Rebol mailing list as one example.

Comment: I Have tried to register on Rebol Mailing List multiple times, It has never worked. And mailing list is so outdated, why do you want to isolate from the rest of the world :)

Comment: The Rebol ML is fully open. There is a complete multiple indexed, fully searchable archive at http://www.rebol.org/ml-index.r

Answer (score 0):

I especially like Nick's new forum, http://rebolforum.com/ I'm not sure how frequently gurus check that forum but it's a nice place to ask questions.

Comment: Oops, I would add this as a comment not an answer :?